# Send SMTP email to distribution list with java

Tags: java, email, smtp, mail-server

I have the following java code to create a connection to a SMTP server to send an email. If "distList@mydomain.com" is a single receiver, it works. However, if it is a distribution list, like I would like it to be, it does not.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    SendEmail send = new SendEmail();
    send.sendEmail();
}

private void sendEmail(){
    try {
      smtpSocket = new Socket(host, port);
      os = new DataOutputStream(smtpSocket.getOutputStream());
      is = new DataInputStream(smtpSocket.getInputStream());

      if(smtpSocket != null && os != null && is != null)
      { 
          try                        
          {   os.writeBytes("HELO\r\n");
              os.writeBytes("MAIL From: <mySender@mydomain.com>\r\n");
              os.writeBytes("RCPT To: <distList@mydomain.com>\r\n");

              os.writeBytes("DATA\r\n");                            
              os.writeBytes("X-Mailer: Via Java\r\n");
              os.writeBytes("DATE: " + dFormat.format(dDate) + "\r\n");
              os.writeBytes("From: Me <mySender@mydomain.com>\r\n");
              os.writeBytes("To:  You <distList@mydomain.com>\r\n");

              String sMessage = "This is the body of the message.";

              os.writeBytes("Subject: Your subjectline here\r\n\r\n");
              os.writeBytes(sMessage + "\r\n");
              os.writeBytes("\r\n.\r\n");
              os.writeBytes("QUIT\r\n");


              String responseline;
              while((responseline = is.readLine())!=null)
              {   
                  System.out.println(responseline);
                  if(responseline.indexOf("Ok") != -1)
                      break;
              }
          }
          catch(Exception e)
          {  System.out.println("Cannot send email as an error occurred.");  }
      }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    { System.out.println("Host " + m_sHostName + " unknown"); }
}

}
```

The response from the server is the same regardless of if its a single recipient or the desired distribution list:

220 *host* Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at *currentTimestamp*

250 *host* Hello [*myIP*]

250 2.1.0 Sender OK

250 2.1.5 Recipient OK

354 Please start mail input.

250 Mail queued for delivery.

221 Closing connection. Good bye.

Does anyone know why I can successfully send to a single person, but not a distribution list?

Comment: This code should not be even aware if the recipient is a distributionlist or a regular e-mail address. It works the same way (and correctly), as you have already verified it. The problem is likely with your distribution list. Can you send a test e-mail to that distribution address from a regular client? If that works, can you access the mail server logs to get more info on what is happening on server side?

Comment: I can send an email to the list from outlook correctly, yes. and Ill have to ask the system admin

Comment: @Tim, Did you find the answer ?